# How to configuration of datasource in war instead of standalone.xml

Tags: jboss, datasource

I have working on datasource in wildfly jboss server configuration I want to configure datasource in application that is inside war file, please help me with this thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to deploy a `*-ds.xml` file with your data source definition. Nevertheless, this way of DS definition is not recommended!

The format looks like:

```xml
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjaca
mar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/GreeterQuickstartDS"
        pool-name="greeter-quickstart" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:greeter-quickstart;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
            <password>sa</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

You can put the `*-ds.xml` files directly into the `standalone/deployments` directory or call JBoss CLI `deploy` command:

```
deploy /path/to/your-custom-ds.xml
```

You can also put the `*-ds.xml` file into the `WEB-INF` directory directly in your web application.

```
$ unzip -l target/greeter.war |grep ds.xml
      684  2019-11-10 18:53   WEB-INF/greater-ds.xml
```